# Print two lines at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

I have this problem, I need to print 2 lines at the same time for the same file, the problem is that it must occur following the row changes in the first column, e.g.:

file: abcd.csv

```
a,1
a,2
a,3
a,4
a,5
a,6
b,1
b,2
b,3
b,4
b,5
b,6
c,1
c,2
c,3
c,4
c,5
c,6
```

code:

```
awk '{ if ( $1 == "a") print $1,$2 } ' FS="," abcd.csv
```

which prints:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 5
a 6
```

but I need two lines at the same time, because I need to pipe these two rows to an additional call:

1st output (then they will be sent):

```
a 1
a 2
```

2nd output (then they will be sent):

```
a 2
a 3
```

3rd output (then they will be sent):

```
a 3
a 4
```

4th output (then they will be sent):

```
a 4
a 5
```

5th output (then they will be sent):

```
a 5
a 6
```

and so forth for the other letters in the first column.

I'd appreciate any hints on this,

Comment: Does this have to be in `awk`?

Comment: You need to double each transition line? What happens when the second field doesn't change between two lines `a 1` `a 2` `a 2` `a 3`?

Comment: so you want to each time call your awk, you got two lines, first, line 1,2, then 3,4 ... that is, if you call 100 times, you parse the file 100 times... I suggest you grep/awk... to get all lines you need, then handle on that smaller set, with looping.

Comment: @user1146334 much better with awk but I receive suggestions

Comment: @EtanReisner sorry but I didn't understand your question, I need the output I put above, the 1st output both together (`a 1` in the first row, and `a 2` in the next row), it seems an easy task but haven't found how to do it with awk so far.

Comment: @Kent well, the file has only 31 records, so if the first column has 6 rows with the letter `a`, I'd need 5 outputs as above

Comment: You want to run your script multiple times to get each pair of output lines? Or you want to duplicate input lines to make the output pairs you expect? What happens when the second column doesn't change? Do you pair up `a 2` and `a 2`? Do you output `a 2` `a 2` `a 3`? What?

Comment: @Gery even if your file has only 4 rows, that is the worst way to do the job. and not easier, you still need loop, you still need pass variable to awk to let it know which round.  If you know you are going on the wrong way, and not saving effort, but you keep going... what I can tell is just "good luck"

Comment: What does your additional call look like? You say you have to pipe the result to an additional call. Maybe everything can be done from a single `awk` script if you tell us more about your setting..

Comment: @Kent that's your opinion and I respect it, but don't share it. Thanks for the wishes, ebenso, aber ich wûnsche Ihnen auch viel Erfolg

Comment: @EtanReisner thanks for your interest, but don't worry, several clever guys gave me already an answer, they did understood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `getline()` function inside an infinite loop, and break it when first field is different from `a` character:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        while (1) {
            prev_line = $0
            r = getline
            if (r != 1) {
                exit r
            }
            split(prev_line, arr_prev, /,/)
            split($0, arr, /,/)
            if (arr_prev[1] == "a" && arr[1] == "a") {
                printf "%s\n%s\n", prev_line, $0
            }
            else {
                exit 0
            }
            print "============="
        }
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
a,1 
a,2 
============= 
a,2 
a,3 
============= 
a,3 
a,4 
============= 
a,4 
a,5 
============= 
a,5 
a,6 
=============
```

---

**UPDATE**: To avoid an infinite loop I added a check in the `getline()` result to exit in end of file or an error.

Comment: This solution WILL produce a TRULY infinite loop in some situations. If you're considering using getline make sure you read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and FULLY understand all the implications and caveats. This does not seem like an appropriate problem for a getline solution.

Comment: I don't get it though - you're completely circumventing awks natural processing loop and adding your own. I don't understand why you'd want to do that and if you are going to do it then why do it on the first line of the file instead of in the BEGIN section and then why write a while(1) loop with a break instead of giving the loop a real condition? All rhetorical... just some head scratching on my part!

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes. You are right. It was my first plan and perhaps I didn't think about it in depth, but, hey, it seems to work!. Fortunately the OP has many other solutions to choose better designed than this one.

Answer (score 3):

You need to manage this after your awk call:

```
awk -F, '$1 == "a" {print $1,$2}' abcd.csv | 
while read line1; do
    read line2
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" | additional_call
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question what you mean by "two lines at the same time", but the below code will output in two line groups within each letter:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=","; OFS=","}
{
    count[$1]++;
    rows[$1][count[$1]] = $2;
}
END {
    for(i in count) {
        for(k=1; k<=count[i]-1; k++) {
            print i,rows[i][k]
            print i,rows[i][k+1] 
            print ""
        }
        print ""
            print ""
        }
    }
```

This code sets the input and output field separator to be a comma. It then creates a 2D hash with the first letter and the line within that letter group as the keys, and the second column as the value.

Finally it goes through the 2D hash for each initial letter and the group row value printing in groups of two within that letter's set.

Output base on your given input:

```
a,1
a,2

a,2
a,3

a,3
a,4

a,4
a,5

a,5
a,6



b,1
b,2

b,2
b,3

b,3
b,4

b,4
b,5

b,5
b,6



c,1
c,2

c,2
c,3

c,3
c,4

c,4
c,5

c,5
c,6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `awk` then a simple `python` program would suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(content)-1):
    if content[i].split(',')[0] == content[i+1].split(',')[0]:
        print content[i]
        print content[i+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you need to pipe each two lines so some other call, if you produce all the output in one go then you'd still need to split each pair of lines in order to make this other call.

I'd just do the following in bash,

```
    FILE=abcd.csv; \
    LINES=`wc -l $FILE | cut -d' ' -f1`; \
    for N in `seq 2 ${LINES}`; do \
        head -n${N} $FILE | tail -n2 | awk '{print $1,$2}' FS="," | cat;  \
    done
```

Replace the last `| cat` before the `done` with the call you actually want to make, this will receive each pair of lines.